# 404 Error From OAuth Token URL

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, onelogin

using this URL as a reference and attempting token exchange with client ID and secret:

https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/oauth20-tokens/generate-tokens

I get a 404 error for the URL provided. I'm using:

https://api.us.onelogin.com/auth/oauth2/token

Am I missing something from the docs? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API is working for me. Just curious - are you using the POST method?

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that a 404 is returned if I don't use the right method. I'm using post now and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the CURL example at the bottom of the doc page?

Just to be clear, you need to sub in your shard, which is prob `us`.

Like

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: client_id:{enteryours}, client_secret:{enteryours}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "grant_type":"client_credentials" }' 'https://api.us.onelogin.com/auth/oauth2/token'